# jQuery parse/display json data from php json_encode

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json

Initial .ajax call in jquery:

```
$.ajax({                                      
 type: 'post',
 url: 'items_data.php',                  
 data: "id="+id,                                       
 dataType: 'json',                     
 success: function(data){     
  if(data){
   make_item_rows(data);
  }else{
   alert("oops nothing happened :(");
  }        
 } 
});
```

Sends a simple string to a php file which looks like:

```
header('Content-type: application/json');
require_once('db.php');

if( isset($_POST['id'])){
 $id = $_POST['id'];
}else{
 echo "Danger Will Robinson Danger!";
}

$items_data = $pdo_db->query ("SELECT blah blah blah with $id...");
$result_array = $items_data->fetchAll();
echo json_encode($result_array);
```

I am catching the $result_array just fine and passing it on to another function.  I double checked that there is indeed proper values being returned as I can just echo result to my page and it displays something like the following:

```
[{"item_id":"230","0":"230","other_id":"700"},{"item_id":"231","0":"231","other_id":"701"},{"item_id":"232","0":"232","other_id":"702"}]
```

I am having trouble figuring out how to iterate through the results so I can inject values into a table I have in my HTML.  Here is what I have for my function:

```
function make_item_rows(result_array){  
 var string_buffer = "";
 $.each(jQuery.parseJSON(result_array), function(index, value){
  string_buffer += value.item_id; //adding many more eventually
  $(string_buffer).appendTo('#items_container');
  string_buffer = ""; //reset buffer after writing          
 });                    
}
```

I also tried putting an alert in the $.each function to make sure it was firing 3 times, which it was.  However no data comes out of my code.  Have tried some other methods as well with no luck.

UPDATE:  I changed my code to include the parseJSON, no dice.  Got an unexpected token error in my jquery file (right when it attempts to use native json parser).  Tried adding the json header to no avail, same error. jquery version 1.9.1.  Code as it is now should be reflected above.

Comment: Also wanted to point something out that might have been very important.  .appendTo() did not work for this solution.  Only .append() worked.  I have no idea why according to jQuery documentation, either should work.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Set the `dataType:"JSON"` and callback in your ajax call.

For example:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "yourphp.php?id="+yourid,
    dataType: "JSON",
    success: function(json){
        //here inside json variable you've the json returned by your PHP
        for(var i=0;i<json.length;i++){
            $('#items_container').append(json[i].item_id)
        }
    }
})
```

Please also consider in your PHP set the JSON content-type. `header('Content-type: application/json');`

Comment: OMG!  I love you!  This is the only solution that worked.  I've been going at this for too many hours.  My json data was coming back in a way that seemed slightly different from the tutorials and examples I was looking at, in terms of how the array was formed.  Worked like a freaking charm!

Comment: You need to make json a string, "JSON" and add commas after every parameter. Otherwise this answer worked for me as well.

Answer (score 1):

You need to parse it with `jQuery.parseJSON`

```
function make_item_rows(result_array){  
 var string_buffer = "";
 $.each(jQuery.parseJSON(result_array), function(index, value){
  string_buffer = value.item_id;
  $(string_buffer).appendTo('#items_container');
 });                    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function make_item_rows(result_array){  
    var string_buffer = "";
    var parsed_array=JSON.parse(result_array);
    $.each(parsed_array, function(){
       string_buffer += parsed_array.item_id;
       $(string_buffer).appendTo('#items_container');
       string_buffer = "";           
    });                    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
function make_item_rows(result_array){  
 var string_buffer = "";
 $.each(result_array, function(index, value){
  value = jQuery.parseJSON(value);
  string_buffer += value.item_id;
  $(string_buffer).appendTo('#items_container');
  string_buffer = "";           
 });                    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you already parsed the json response and you have the array. I think the problem is you need to pass a callback to $.each that takes and index and an element param

```
function make_item_rows(result_array){  
    $.each(result_array, function(index, element){
        document.getElementById("a").innerHTML+=element.item_id;
    });                    
}
```

[(Slightly modified) DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/cead22/x5AZ9/)

Answer (score 0):

for starters within the `$.each` you need to access the properties of the instance of object contained within `result_array`, not `result_array` itself.

```
var string_buffer = "";
 $.each(result_array, function(index, object){
     /* instance is "object"*/
     alert( object.item_id);
});
```

Not entirely sure what you are expecting from this line: `$(string_buffer).appendTo('#items_container');`

`$(string_buffer)` does not create a valid jQuery selector since nothing within `string_buffer` has a prefix for class, tagname or ID, and values from json don't either

If just want the string value of the `item_id` appended :

```
$('#items_container').append(  object.item_id+'<br/>');
```

If you are receiving this using jQuery AJAX methods you don't need to use `$.parseJSON` as other answers suggest, it will already be done for you internally provided you are setting correct dataType for AJAX

Comment: I think .append() and .appendTo() do pretty much the same thing. http://api.jquery.com/appendTo/

Comment: @carter only if selector, DOM element or html string in `$()` is valid...which in this case it is not and will simply fail quietly

Comment: really help if you outline objective of your code. Can help more that way. Broken code is often not a good substute for a verbal explanation of goals and expected output. A sample of table html would also help a lot.If `$('#container') is a table you need to create a valid html row to append to it

Comment: yeah sorry I cut out a lot of the code to try to make it more simple.  I can complete all the html and formatting once I can iterate through the json object/array/whatever it is.  I updated code above to try and give more info.  #items_container is just a div tag right now for testing.  Just trying to get the 3 item_id's to show up first.  When I just echo json_encode from the .php file without doing anything with the data, you get the [{},{},{}] shown above.  Thanks for help :)

Comment: Charlie, just wanted to say thanks.  You were right and jQuery documentation was wrong on this one.  It did make a difference between .append and .appendTo()

Comment: @carter they do actually achieve same thing but can't put arbitrary text data in `$()`. Could put `$('<div>'+object.item_id+'</div>').appendTo..` and that would resolve to valid html and work fine. `append()` on the ther hand can be straight text

Comment: Yeah I see what you are saying now, but the documentation is confusing in how it words this. Thanks again for the help.  :)

Comment: generally easiest to use append mostly because is easier reading left to right where-then-what, IMO